# RegEx: My Expression doesn't match nested group

Tags: .net, regex

The following Regular Expression (url) pattern doesn't match the named group :

```
^/(.+?)/(.+)?(_p(?<Page>\d+))?
```

I don't know why this doesn't work in optional block:

```
?()?
```

What's the problem with this pattern and how can i get the correct result?

Comment: Can you post samples of the input and what you expect to be matched? We can't guess from just looking at the regex.

Comment: e.g. "/Directory/File_p2" i test the patterns with a Regex-Lab http://www.mycsharp.de/wbb2/thread.php?threadid=21580 - i've tested a lot but i never get the correct result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd group `(.+)?` is greedy. Therefore it will match the whole `File_p2`. Since the 3rd group is optional, it will just be skipped.

You could change the regex to

```
^/([^/]+)/(.+?)(?:_p(?<Page>\d+))?$
```

or, slightly more efficiently,

```
^/([^/]+)/([^_]+(?:_[^_]+)*?)(?:_p(?<Page>\d+))?$
```

Comment: "/Directory/File" as base file and "/Directory/File_p2" etc... so the <Page> groupe needs to be optional

Comment: @Beni: (1) Will file names like `foo_bar_p2` be allowed? (2) Is the Directory a single directory or `/has/a/lot/of/components/`?

Comment: There is only one directory and one file in this case (there are other cases, but i need one as template to create the others). foo_bar_p2 is allowed (base file is in this case: foo_bar - e.g. "/Dir_1/File_1" and "/Dir_1/File_1_p2"